# emgucv bodydetection using haarcascade

Tags: c#, winforms, emgucv

I'm trying to develop an application that would detect the upper body and lower body of a person through a webcam. I tried to look at emgu's face detection and downloaded "haarcascade_upperbody.xml" and "haarcascade_lowerbody.xml". I tried to code something same with the face detection given

But the problem is that it won't detect my body and it's not in real-time any more. It delays by 3 seconds?

Here's my code. I hope someone can help me:

```
private void ProcessFrame(object sender, EventArgs arg)
    {
        Image<Bgr, Byte> ImageFrame = capture.QueryFrame();
        FittingBox.Image = ImageFrame;

        long detectionTime;

        List<Rectangle> upper = new List<Rectangle>();
        List<Rectangle> lower = new List<Rectangle>();
        Detect(ImageFrame,"haarcascade_upperbody.xml","haarcascade_lowerbody.xml",upper,lower,out detectionTime);
        foreach (Rectangle up in upper)
            ImageFrame.Draw(up, new Bgr(Color.Red), 2);
        foreach (Rectangle low in lower)
            ImageFrame.Draw(low, new Bgr(Color.Blue), 2);
    }



 public static void Detect(Image<Bgr, Byte> image, String upperFileName, String lowerFileName, List<Rectangle> upperbody, List<Rectangle> lowerbody, out long detectionTime)
    {
        Stopwatch watch;

        if (GpuInvoke.HasCuda)
        {
            using (GpuCascadeClassifier upper = new GpuCascadeClassifier(upperFileName))
            using (GpuCascadeClassifier lower = new GpuCascadeClassifier(lowerFileName))
            {
                watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                using (GpuImage<Bgr, Byte> gpuImage = new GpuImage<Bgr, byte>(image))
                using (GpuImage<Gray, Byte> gpuGray = gpuImage.Convert<Gray, Byte>())
                {
                    Rectangle[] upperRegion = upper.DetectMultiScale(gpuGray, 1.1, 10, Size.Empty);
                    upperbody.AddRange(upperRegion);
                    foreach (Rectangle f in upperRegion)
                    {
                        using (GpuImage<Gray, Byte> upperImg = gpuGray.GetSubRect(f))
                        {
                            using (GpuImage<Gray, Byte> clone = upperImg.Clone())
                            {
                                Rectangle[] lowerRegion = lower.DetectMultiScale(clone, 1.1, 10, Size.Empty);

                                foreach (Rectangle e in lowerRegion)
                                {
                                    Rectangle lowerRect = e;
                                    lowerRect.Offset(f.X, f.Y);
                                    lowerbody.Add(lowerRect);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                watch.Stop();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            using (CascadeClassifier upper = new CascadeClassifier(upperFileName))
            using (CascadeClassifier lower = new CascadeClassifier(lowerFileName))
            {
                watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                using (Image<Gray, Byte> gray = image.Convert<Gray, Byte>())
                {
                    gray._EqualizeHist();
                    Rectangle[] upperDeteced = upper.DetectMultiScale(
                        gray,
                        1.1,
                        10,
                        new Size(50, 50),
                        Size.Empty);

                    foreach (Rectangle f in upperDeteced)
                    {
                        gray.ROI = f;

                        Rectangle[] lowerDetected = lower.DetectMultiScale(
                            gray,
                            1.1,
                            10,
                            new Size(50, 50),
                            Size.Empty);
                        gray.ROI = Rectangle.Empty;

                        foreach (Rectangle e in lowerDetected)
                        {
                            Rectangle lowerRect = e;
                            lowerRect.Offset(f.X, f.Y);
                            lowerbody.Add(lowerRect);
                        }
                    }
                }
                watch.Stop();
            }
        }
        detectionTime = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    }
```

Comment: Can you formulate clearly what is the problem? As for "real time", it's not clear enough. What is the resolution of your picture? How many frame per second? Does it detect other upper body?

Comment: The problem is the system can't detect any... I want to draw a rectangle on the captured upper body but it doesn't draw... all my codes are stated above...

Comment: Did you try a very simple test before doing this? Like just trying to detect the upper body? Because right now, it seems you try to find the upper body and then, if you find it, try to find the lower body. The chance that these 2 are found in one image is very low. And to find people, you should use the PeopleDetector in the HoGDescriptor.

Comment: yes I already did try detecting only the upper body still the same... so I should use the pedestrian detector instead of the face detection?
can I still use haarcascade with pedestrian detector?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best way to find a human body in a upright position is the Pedestrian Detector that comes shipped with OpenCV. You don't need any training since it's already implemented in the HogDescriptor.

See [this example](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Pedestrian_Detection_in_CSharp) for emguCV. As for your code using cascade, I have never tried these pre-trained cascade so I don't know for which kind of image they have been trained.

Comment: but the thing is I need to differentiate the upper body from the lower body... upper body has a different measurement... and so does the lower body... if I will be using pedestrian it only detects the whole body as is...

Comment: Oh! I didn't know that! Then you can try to detect the whole body using the pedestrian detector, create a ROI and then run the haar cascade on the small region. It will be very fast and have a bigger chance to find it. But I would not try to detect the lower body only if the upper body is found. Try to find each of them separately, and if you just found one (for example the lower body), you can extrapolate the height of the upper body by substracting the height of the total body minus the lower body. Just an idea! Use your imagination :)

Answer (score 0):

This is old one, but the cost of time is of more interest to me.

As you say

> " but address the both the problems "

1. is that it won't detect my body and
2. it's not in real-time any more. It delays by 3 seconds?

Starting with #2 first:

Let's assume by 3 seconds you mean it's taking 3 seconds to apply the haar cascades. IMHO & experience, that is due to a number of factors.

The time to process a haar cascade is equivilent to the size of the target object in terms of number of pixels height and width and also the parameters used.

Additionally, the DetectMultiScale parameters will effect performance.  On my fairly beefy machine, I'm seeing MP4 frame width of 1280x720 taking 1.5 seconds to process an image with the following settings:

```
    scaleFactor = 1.07
    minNeighbors = 2 
    minSize = 8,8
    maxSize = 200,200
```

A "webm" 720p is able to process the same settings in 1 second.  You can tune your classifiers to make it faster or slower by playing with these settings. I put some controls on the screen for my mine samples and tuned them a bit.

On simple smaller single test jpg images, it's fairly fast like 200 ms.

The HOG FindPedestrian.Find is pretty fast and accurate at finding whole bodies in about 1/10 the time 150ms, which is almost fast enough for about 7 fps (frames per second) again that's on my I7 (not using GPU).

In terms of your 1st problem:

## 1>  is that it won't detect my body and?

Ok, the code snippet your borrowed from the EMGU sample, is a detect an Eye inside a face.

- Eyes go inside faces.
- Lower bodies are not found inside of upper bodies.

If you used the Hog to find the relative location of the body and then pass that image snippet to the detector for haar lower & upper it might be significantly faster responses, rather than scanning the whole image.

I think that you're going to have to play/tweak with the settings to find anything.

Also fix the logic of find a lower inside an upper.